# How to separate the day from date created and put into the graph?

Tags: php, database

I am really new into implementing my data into graphs. Yesterday I was working with pie graphs and finished my work with it. Now, I have stumbled across implementing a bar graph which has two bars per month which I would like to make. I have seen a couple of sample bar graphs. In my database, I have two tables for two types of users(Stylist and Client). When I register into a certain user type, there would be a `date_created` column in my table indicating the creation of the account. As to all user tables. Its format is in `2019-02-16` so it is in yy-mm--dd. What I am planning is to get the month in the middle and also the year, and in my graph (2bars per month, has a sample code from the web) will be for each table. Can you sirs help me out with this? I really don't understand on how to implement this one.

This is my php file.

```
<?php $connect = mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");  

//THIS IS THE FIRST BAR for the graph, it needs to be replaced with my data
$dataPoints1 = array(
        array("label"=> "2010", "y"=> 36.12),
        array("label"=> "2011", "y"=> 34.87),
        array("label"=> "2012", "y"=> 40.30),
        array("label"=> "2013", "y"=> 35.30),
        array("label"=> "2014", "y"=> 39.50),
        array("label"=> "2015", "y"=> 50.82),
        array("label"=> "2016", "y"=> 74.70)
    ); 
    //THIS IS THE SECOND BAR in the graph and also needs my data
    $dataPoints2 = array(
        array("label"=> "2010", "y"=> 64.61),
        array("label"=> "2011", "y"=> 70.55),
        array("label"=> "2012", "y"=> 72.50),
        array("label"=> "2013", "y"=> 81.30),
        array("label"=> "2014", "y"=> 63.60),
        array("label"=> "2015", "y"=> 69.38),
        array("label"=> "2016", "y"=> 98.70)
 );


 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
<script>
        window.onload = function () {

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            animationEnabled: true,
            theme: "light2",
            title:{
                text: "Users registered every month"
            },
            legend:{
                cursor: "pointer",
                verticalAlign: "center",
                horizontalAlign: "right",
                itemclick: toggleDataSeries
            },
            data: [{
                type: "column",
                name: "Real Trees",
                indexLabel: "{y}",
                yValueFormatString: "$#0.##",
                showInLegend: true,
                dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
            },{
                type: "column",
                name: "Artificial Trees",
                indexLabel: "{y}",
                yValueFormatString: "$#0.##",
                showInLegend: true,
                dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints2, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
            }]
        });
        chart.render();

        function toggleDataSeries(e){
            if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                e.dataSeries.visible = false;
            }
            else{
                e.dataSeries.visible = true;
            }
            chart.render();
        }

        }
        </script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Admin</title>
      <div  id="piechart" style="width: 625px; height: 400px; border: 3px solid black; border-radius: 25px; margin-bottom: 20px; padding: 10px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use `JSON.stringify()` function from there you can easily decode or `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 0):

using Date_format function in your query you can get month and year

```
DATE_FORMAT($date,'%d-%b-%Y');
```

for month

```
DATE_FORMAT($date,'%b');
```

Comment: thanks for helping out sir! I'm sorry i was away from town at the moment and I have just checked this post just now. I have already solved it at ease sir! hihi thanks!